# Likelihood ratio test

Tags: probability, statistics

Problem 47, pg 296 from Jun Shao: Mathematical statistics

Let $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ be a random sample from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Suppose that $\sigma^2 = \gamma \mu^2$ with unknown $\gamma >0$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$. Find likelihood ratio test for testing $H_0: \gamma=1$ vs. $H_1: \gamma\neq 1$

I first found the MLE for both $\mu$ and $\gamma$: $\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $\hat{\gamma} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\bar{X}^2}$.

The $LR(\theta_0) = 2 \Bigg(L(\hat{\theta_n}) - L(\theta_0)\Bigg) \sim \chi^2(1)$ as $n \to \infty$.

My log-likelihood is $$L(\mu,\gamma) = -n \log\sqrt{2\pi} -n \log \sqrt{\gamma} - n \log{\mu} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2}{2 \mu^2 \gamma}$$

I plug everything $(\gamma_0=1)$ in and end up with

$$|LR(\gamma_0)| =| 2 \Bigg(L(\hat{\gamma_n})- L(\gamma_0)\Bigg)|= | n \log \Bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\bar{X}^2} \Bigg) - n + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\bar{X}^2}| > \chi^2(1,\alpha)$$

Is my analysis correct? (It's a different approach than the book is presenting)